# Firefox install

Tags: browser

I know I probably sound like a retard but I downloaded firefox earlier to replace netsurf because of stupid errors and I don't know how to open a browser that isn't netsurf. I have firefox-28.0.tar.bz2 downloaded and I need help to open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox is installed by default on Ubuntu. But if you're using a different variant and don't have it, you can download it using the command

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

then press Enter. You will be asked to enter the privileged account password to proceed.

For more information about installing Firefox on Ubuntu, follow the links below

1. [HowTo Install the Latest Firefox in Ubuntu (Ultimate HowTo)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=330386)
2. [Firefox New Version - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion)
3. [Install Firefox on Linux | Firefox Help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux)